# Largest possible difference between "round numbers" (multiples of powers of 10) that contain a given interval

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, logarithms, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I came up with this problem while trying to write code to create limits for a plot that are nice round numbers, given an arbitrary range of data. I have an intuition that the answer is 10, but I can't quite prove it.

**Problem Statement**

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two real numbers with $A < B$. Let $C$ be the largest power of $10$ that is less than or equal to $B - A$. Let $A'$ be the largest multiple of $C$ that is less than or equal to $A$, and $B'$ be the largest multiple of $C$ that is greater than or equal to $B$. What is the maximum possible value of
> $$
> \frac{B' - A'}{C}?
> $$

**Proof that the Answer is at Most $12$**
$$
C = 10^{\lfloor \log_{10}(B-A) \rfloor} 
> 10^{\log_{10}(B-A) - 1} 
= \frac{B-A}{10}
$$
and $A' = C\lfloor \frac{A}{C} \rfloor$ and $B' = C\lceil \frac{B}{C} \rceil$.

Therefore,
$$
\frac{B'-A'}{C} 
= \biggl\lceil \frac{B}{C} \biggr\rceil 
- \biggl\lfloor \frac{A}{C} \biggr\rfloor 
< \frac{B}{C} + 1 - \biggl(\frac{A}{C} - 1\biggr) 
= \frac{B-A}{C} + 2 
< \frac{B-A}{(B-A)/10} + 2 = 12
$$

Again, I'm pretty sure the answer here is actually $10$, but I'm not sure how to shave off that final $2$ in the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:
$$B-A<10C$$
$$A-A'<C$$
$$B\,'-B<C$$
Adding these up,
$$B\,'-A'<12C$$
And $B\,'-A'$ is a multiple of $C$, so $(B\,'-A')/C\le 11$.

And this is the best we can do: if $A=9$ and $B=108$, then $C=10$, and we get $A'=0, B\,'=110, (B\,'-A')/C=11$.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Just a minor correction: since A and B are real numbers, I think rather than "1" you would use some arbitrarily small "epsilon" there, but the logic still works the same way.

Comment: @Izzhov: Yes, you are right of course. I have edited my answer accordingly.